# I want to return the 'a' of the URL instead of the whole URL

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

How would I get my current code to return the 'a' of the link instead of the whole link. Here is how I return the whole link, but I want just the 'a'.

```
item ['Url'] = response.url
```

For example http://international.southwales.ac.uk/country/iran/en/ would be 'Iran'.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from project.items import QualificationItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin


USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'usw1'
allowed_domains = ['international.southwales.ac.uk''eu.southwales.ac.uk/']
start_urls = ['http://international.southwales.ac.uk/countries']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/a/@href'
    for link in hxs.select(xpath).extract():
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link),
                      headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT},
                      callback=self.parse_linkpage,
                      dont_filter=True)

def parse_linkpage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = QualificationItem()
    xpath = """
            //h4[normalize-space(.)="Entry Requirements - Undergraduate"]
             /following-sibling::ul/li
            """
    item['Qualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()[0:1]
    item['Url'] = response.url

    return item
```

Comment: What does "the 'a' of the URL" mean? Just "the portion of the url following `http://international.southwales.ac.uk/country/` and preceding `/en/`"? Or something else? If this is just a question about extracting data from url strings, can you remove all of the web-related code from your post, and reduce it to the smallest code sample that replicates your problem?

Comment: Hello sorry I want my code to keep what it's doing and cutting it down would not make sence. By the 'a' I mean the writing on the link, so for example <a href="url/url/url/iran/">Iran</a> I want the Writing bit after the link.

Comment: You mean you want the anchor tag text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by making use of the `meta` attribute of the Request call. The documentation [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) talks about it.

Change your `parse` method to:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/a/@href'
    a_of_the_link = '/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/a/text()'
    for text, link in zip(hxs.select(a_of_the_link).extract(), hxs.select(xpath).extract()):
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link),  meta={'a_of_the_link': text},
                          headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT},
                          callback=self.parse_linkpage,
                          dont_filter=True)
```

And you can access that in your `parse_item` as:

```
item['Url'] = response.meta['a_of_the_link']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Brings up an error - "syntaxerror: invalid syntax" on the headers line

Comment: Nevermind, there was a ',' missing after the meta :) thank you!